# Difference between [] and []() in Swift

Tags: swift

I tried searching around for what this is

```
[]()
```

But I'm not really sure.  In a playground, I did this:

```
var test = [Int]();
test.append(1);
test.append(2);
```

If I leave off the () and do

```
var test = [Int];
test.append(1);
test.append(2);
```

It still looks like an array of Ints to me. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Type()` means "call `init()`" - i.e., make a new instance of `Type`.

`[Int]` is a type, like `String`. `[Int]` means "array-of-Int".

`String()` makes a new empty String instance. `[Int]()` makes a new empty array-of-Int instance.

You can declare a variable as being of type array-of-Int. Or you can make and assign a new array-of-Int instance. Which is what you are doing here:

```
var test = [Int]()
```

But you cannot assign a type to a variable without further syntax. Thus, this is illegal:

```
var test = [Int]
```

**EXTRA for experts**

You *can* say:

```
var test = [Int].self
```

That *does* assign the type to the variable! That is unlikely to be what you want here, because now you have no array; you have a type, itself, as object!!

Comment: And please stop using semicolons. :)

Comment: I would also add that `[]` is an array literal for an empty array i.e. `var test: [Int] = []` is initializing `test` to be an empty array.  `var test: [Int] = [1]` is initializing `test` to be an array with one entry, `var test: [Int] = [1,2]` an array with two entries etc.  When you initialize with some entries, Swift can "infer" the type – so you can write `var test = [1,2]` without the type because it can see that the array contains `Int` (the default type for integer literals).  But when you declare an empty array, you have to give a type as Swift has nothing else to go on.

Comment: In some contexts (e.g. last argument to a function call), a type can be used as a value without further syntax

Comment: @newacct I'm glad you've figured out when it is. I always just try the type name alone and then add `.self` if the compiler complains. :)

Answer (score 0):

`[Type]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<Type>`, so it represents the array type, which is a generic struct, and for which you specify the type of elements it holds (`Int` in this example)

So the difference between:

```
[Int]
```

and

```
[Int]()
```

is the same as for

```
Array<Int>
```

and

```
Array<Int>()
```

The first is just a type, which you can use when declaring a variable or a function parameter.

The second invokes the parameterless constructor on that type, i.e. creates an instance of that type.